# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined from props

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm stacked so long.

Regarding to following code, when I get members object from state, it is not recognized as array object.

So I wrote dummy_member from copy text, it works and recognized as array object.

```
    render() {
        const members = this.props.members; // <- Get from state.
        console.log(members); //Show Array Object (1)
        console.log(members.length); //Error

        const dummy_members = [{xx:xxx},..]; // <- Copied & paste text from JSON data on browser from server.
        console.log(dummy_members); // Show Array Object (2)
        console.log(dummy_members.length); // It shows array length.
```

both console.log shows following result.

```
(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 3, away_team_p1_shots: 20, away_team_p2_score: 4, …}
1: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 1, away_team_p1_shots: 13, away_team_p2_score: 2, …}
2: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 1, away_team_p1_shots: 15, away_team_p2_score: 2, …}
3: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 2, away_team_p1_shots: 15, away_team_p2_score: 3, …}
4: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 6, away_team_p1_shots: 23, away_team_p2_score: 9, …}
5: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 0, away_team_p1_shots: 10, away_team_p2_score: 2, …}
6: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 1, away_team_p1_shots: 12, away_team_p2_score: 1, …}
7: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 1, away_team_p1_shots: 19, away_team_p2_score: 1, …}
8: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 0, away_team_p1_shots: 10, away_team_p2_score: 2, …}
9: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 3, away_team_p1_shots: 16, away_team_p2_score: 4, …}
10: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 0, away_team_p1_shots: 8, away_team_p2_score: 1, …}
11: {away_team_ot_score: 0, away_team_ot_shots: 0, away_team_p1_score: 0, away_team_p1_shots: 8, away_team_p2_score: 1, …}
length: 12
```

It seems not to be wrong.

My Question is both members (1) and dummy_members (2) have same console log, however both has different result. members from props (1) had not been recognized as array.

I would like to get members object from this.props.members.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it an array or array like object

Comment: Do you know how to recognize them?

Comment: Or how to convert one to another?

Comment: Check the typeof of both  members and dummy_members.

Comment: Both returns object.

Comment: Oh sorry you cannot check it from typeof because both array and objects are return object type. Maybe you wrapped your original members data in an object from parent component ? Like, <Parent members={data}/>

Comment: You can check by using `isArray` for arrays.

Comment: What Error is thrown here? `console.log(members.length); //Error`

Comment: Both isArray are undefined.

Comment: `console.log(Array.isArray(members))`

Comment: @Matt Long Error is same as this thread title.

Comment: by any chance is this `this.props.members` undefined in initial render?

Comment: If the props data are getting from  async operation,  you have no props data in initial render. So it throws an error.

Comment: @Aprillion  Both recognized as Array. dummy:true / members:true.

Comment: Please can you show the code where you have passed in the `members` prop to this Component?

Comment: I initialize `this.state = { members: [] }` in component constructor.

Comment: try this, `if(typeof props.members !== "undefined") { //do console.log here }`

Comment: Actually, I'm using reducer, so I get members like `props.reducer01.members`. It might cause missing initialize.

Comment: Are you using React Hooks `useReducer`? or redux? Or a different state management implementation? Also, just because `this.state` has a `members` property it does not guarantee that `props.members` has a value.

Comment: I found a difference between `props.members` and `props.reducer01.members`.

Comment: First one is not Array, second one is Array.

Comment: @Matt Long I'm using `Redux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `reducer01` does not always contain a `members` array, then `const members = reducer01.members` will be undefined and `members.length` will throw the error you observe.

To guard against undefined, you can use `console.log(members && members.length)`.

(To help you fix the reducer, you will have to share code of the reducer in your question.)

Comment: const initData = {
    members: [],
}

export function reducer01(state = initData, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_MEMBERS':
            return {
                ... state,
                members: action.members
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

Comment: Can you please add your `mapStateToProps()` method and `Action creator` that responsible for fetching data

Comment: I guess you are right. But how can I do for it. My understanding is initializing at `this.state = {members: []}` is enough. Is it my misunderstand?

Comment: Now my code has `export default connect((state)=>state)(Page01);`

Comment: initial state is only used one time, if `action.members` is undefined, then the reducer will return a state with `{members: undefined}` regardless of initializing

Comment: The problem is why these object does not recognized as array?

Comment: I don't know `render()` is called 3 times. the first and second call shows `Array.isArray(members)` false. the third times shows true. I have to prevent not to be undefined.

Comment: well, undefined is not an array, you might have a typo somewhere, e.g. `action.payload.members` or something completely different, but we cannot debug code that you we don't see ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: to prevent first 2 times, you will have to define `const initData = {members: []}` in the scope of `reducer01`

Comment: I added `members: []` all of reduce cases. It worked. But I'm not sure it is good way to fix.